# Django ORM create rows dynamically with _meta.get_fields()

Tags: python, django, orm, row, field

I am writing a function to read xlsx and write this data to the database with Django. But I have so many fields that I cannot define statically. I want to write these fields to the database with a certain algorithm. When designing this, I get the class attributes with _meta.get_fields(). But as seen in this example, attributes always remain None. In views.py there is an example between BEGIN and END codes. How can i solve this problem?

**views.py**

```
# ... some codes ...
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def import_process(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_in_memory = request.FILES['file'].read()
            wb = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(file_in_memory), data_only=True)
            ws = wb.worksheets[0]
            ws_company_name = str(ws["D9"].value)
            ws_company_address = str(ws["D10"].value)
            # ... some codes ...
            # Company Tower Get ID loop
            company_staff = CompanyStaff.objects.filter(company_id=Company.objects.filter(company_name=ws_company_name)[0].id)[0]
            for col in COLUMN_PARAMETER_LIST:
                column_cell = str(col) + str(COLUMN_PARAMETER_BEGIN)
                ws_tower_type = str(ws[column_cell].value)
                tower_type = TowerType.objects.filter(tower_type=ws_tower_type)[0]
                c_tower_object = CompanyTower.objects.filter(company_staff_id=company_staff,tower_type_id=tower_type)[0]
                tower_data = TowerData.objects.create(company_tower_id=c_tower_object)
                ROW_IDX = int(ROW_PARAMETER_BEGIN-1)
                # ****************** BEGIN ****************** #
                site_fields = tower_data._meta.get_fields()
                site_fields_names = [f.name for f in site_fields][1:]
                for mfield in site_fields_names:
                    if any(word in str(mfield) for word in TOWER_DATA_EXCLUDE_FIELDS_NEW):
                        continue
                    else:
                        ROW_IDX += 1
                    tower_data_cell = str(col)+str(ROW_IDX)
                    tower_data_cell_value = ws[tower_data_cell].value
                    tower_data.mfield = tower_data_cell_value
                    if str(mfield) == 'ph': # Example Field
                        print(tower_data.mfield)
                        print(tower_data.ph)
                # ******************* END ******************* #
                tower_data.save()
            print("****************")
    
    return render(request, template_name='import.html',context={"form": UploadFileForm()})
# ... some codes ...
```

[image: Django Admin Panel, row fields are empty]

[image: Django terminal output, tower_data.mfield is None]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently setting and replacing an attribute called `mfield` over and over: `tower_data.mfield = tower_data_cell_value`.

What you want is `setattr(tower_data, mfield, tower_data_cell_value)`

Comment: Thank you so much, I removed this line: "tower_data.mfield = tower_data_cell_value" and added this line: "setattr(tower_data, mfield, tower_data_cell_value)" then problem solved.